# How to setup circular reference in maven modules?

Tags: maven, maven-2, maven-3

I have this problem with building a maven project...

A mvn project parent is set like this:

```
<groupId>com.company.system.ping</groupId>
<artifactId>system-ping</artifactId>
<name>system-ping</name>    
<parent>
    <artifactId>parent_lvl_1</artifactId>
    <groupId>com.company.system</groupId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
</parent>
```

Then I look for said parent's POM and find this:

```
<groupId>com.company.system</groupId>
<artifactId>parent_lvl_1</artifactId>
<packaging>pom</packaging>
<name>_proj_test</name>
<version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
<parent>
    <artifactId>parent_lvl_0</artifactId>
    <groupId>com.company</groupId>
    <version>1</version>
</parent>
```

I finally look at the first parent and see this:

```
<groupId>com.company</groupId>
<artifactId>parent_lvl_0</artifactId>
<packaging>pom</packaging>
<name>_main</name>
<version>1</version>
<description>The whole Projects</description>
```

Now I check the modules:

```
<modules>
    <module>../_proj_test</module>

    ...

</modules>
```

The first parent module is referencing a child! So when I try

> mvn install

on '_main' I get this:

```
[ERROR]   The project com.company.system:_proj_test:1.0-SNAPSHOT (C:\...\pom.xml) has 1 error
[ERROR]     Non-resolvable parent POM: The repository system is offline but the artifact com.company:_main:pom:1 is not available in the local repository. and 'parent.relativePath' points at wrong local POM @ line 4, column 10 -> [Help 2]
[ERROR]
```

I translate this to: ***you parent requieres a module which requires you back***. If I comment out everything in ***modules*** I can install everything correctly but this is NOT OK for me! How can I build the parent without building the module dependencies?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The config looks very weird to me, mainly because your '_proj_test' which is a child for '_main' is located on the same level.

> How can I build the parent without building the module dependencies?

Try *mvn -N install*.

As for the project structure, I'd do it in such a way:

1) $basedir with '_main' pom.xml which should contain this

```
<modules>
  <module>_proj_test</module>
</modules>
```

2) $basedir/_proj_test with '_proj_test' pom.xml which should contain this

```
<modules>
  <module>system-ping</module>
</modules>
```

3) $basedir/_proj_test/system-ping with 'system-ping' pom.xml (with correct *groupId* of parent - *com.company.system* instead of *com.company*)

Comment: I inherited the project from someone else and I believe he wanted a "flat" hierarchy but this works poorly with Maven. I found this: http://www.sonatype.com/books/mvnex-book/reference/multimodule-sect-intro.html.